# SDSF ST via REXX

Tags: mainframe, rexx

I've got an interesting idea. I want to see `JCL` in `SDSF` via `REXX`.

Currently I can see necessary job names, using:

```
Address SDSF "ISFEXEC ST"
```

Maybe anybody has some idea of what to add to my script to make analog of:

```
command s
```

[image]
And totally get the **same output**

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using this[Using SDSF with the REXX programming language - Examples of REXX execs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.isfa500/rexxexmp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

[Using SDSF with the REXX programming language - Examples of REXX execs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.isfa500/rexxexmp.htm), as per the comment, has example code such as:-

> **List action characters**
>
> Set the ISFACTIONS special variable to ON, which causes the action characters to be returned in the ISFRESP variables. Then access the ST panel, and list the valid action characters for that panel.

```
/* REXX */                                         
rc=isfcalls('ON')                                  
    /* Set isfactions special variable to */      
    /* the equivalent of SET ACTION ON    */      
isfactions="ON"                                    
    /* Invoke the ST panel */                     
Address SDSF "ISFEXEC ST"                          
if rc<>0 then                                      
  Exit rc                                          
    /* List each of the valid action characters */
    /* for the panel.                           */
Say "Actions valid on the panel are:"              
do ix=1 to isfresp.0                               
  Say " " isfresp.ix                               
end                                                
rc=isfcalls('OFF')
```

and

> **Access an SDSF panel**
>
> Access the ST panel, then list the column variables.

```
/* REXX */                                     
rc=isfcalls('ON')                              
     /* Access the ST panel */                 
Address SDSF "ISFEXEC ST"                      
if rc<>0 then                                  
  Exit rc                                      
     /* Get fixed field name from first word */
     /* of isfcols special variable          */
fixedField = word(isfcols,1)                      
Say "Number of rows returned:" isfrows            
       /* Process all rows */                       
do ix=1 to isfrows                                
  Say "Now processing job:" value(fixedField"."ix)
          /* List all columns for row */               
  do jx=1 to words(isfcols)           
    col = word(isfcols,jx)                                  
    Say "  Column" col"."ix "has the value:" value(col"."ix)
  end                                                       
end                                                         
rc=isfcalls('OFF')
```

An IBM Red Book, a *PDF Downlaod*, [Implementing Rexx Support in SDSF](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI442jzonNAhWBpZQKHauGDU8QFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fsupport%2Fknowledgecenter%2FSSLTBW_2.1.0%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.isfa500%2Frexx.htm&usg=AFQjCNFvLSaaQGX1TScPIePTkIWPZyLbWw&bvm=bv.123325700,d.dGo) may also be of use.

Comment: UPD:
I copy a little script using https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.isfa500/xmpbrowse.htm
 to see the output of job, which has name "user19". I just change RJONES to user19, and after starting I ve got the result like:
isfmsg2.1 is: ISF767I Request completed.